# Neutron electric dipole moment and $T$ symmetry violation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, time-reversal-symmetry, cpt-symmetry, dipole-moment

Our textbook (and other sources I have found) says that non-zero electric dipole moment of neutron would violate $T$ symmetry. They prove this statement by first assuming $\boldsymbol{D}=\beta\boldsymbol{J}$, where $\boldsymbol{D}$ is the dipole moment, $\boldsymbol{J}$ is the angular momentum, and $\beta$ is a constant.

But why? Why is $\boldsymbol{D}$ proportional to $\boldsymbol{J}$? Why is $\boldsymbol{D}$ related to $\boldsymbol{J}$ at all? And how can't this argument be applied to other composite particles such as atoms and molecules, thereby breaking T symmetry for most of the world?

Comment: In classical mechanics, we have this identity for spinning bodies of charge: $\frac{\mu}{L}=\frac{q}{2m}$, $\mu$ is dipole moment, $L$ is angular momentum. I dunno how this translates to particle physics, but it may help..

Comment: @Manishearth: I'm talking about electric dipole moment, where as $\mu$ is magnetic dipole moment.

Comment: Aah, my bad. Didn't see the 'electric' in the question and i'm not familiar with your usage of symbols (I use p for electric dipole)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the neutron is not point-like, consider it has a continuous distribution of charge $\rho(\mathbf{r})$ confined in a volume $\Omega$. The dipole electric moment is then given by

$\mathbf{D}(\mathbf{r})=\int_\Omega \rho(\mathbf{r}')\delta(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}')d^3r'$

where the coordinates are measured from the centre of mass of the distribution.
For a charged particle, this definition implies that for $\mathbf{D} \neq\mathbf{0}$ the "centre of charge" is displaced from the centre of mass of the distribution. For a distribution which has no net charge, that is

$Q=\int_\Omega \rho(\mathbf{r}) d^3r=0$

this definition implies that a there is a greater positive charge side of your distribution and a correspondingly greater negative charge in the other side.

Consider now that your particle has angular momentum $\mathbf{J}$ and that its orientation is given by $m$ (the eigenvalue of the $\hat{J}_z$ operator) relative to the $\hat{\mathbf{z}}$ axis. Notice that the only way to know the orientation of your charge distribution ("particle") is by the orientation of the angular momentum.

As a consequence, both $\mathbf{J}$ and $\mathbf{D}$ must transform equally under parity $P$ and time reversal $T$ if $\mathbf{D} \neq \mathbf{0}$ and if there is $P$ and $T$ symmetries. But $\mathbf{D}$ changes its sign under $P$ whereas $\mathbf{J}$ does not so $\mathbf{D}$ must vanish if there is $P$ symmetry. In a similar way, $\mathbf{D}$ does not change sign under $T$ but $\mathbf{J}$ does, so $\mathbf{D}$ has to vanish if there is $T$  symmetry. Hence if the neutron electric dipole is not zero we will have a violation of $PT$ symmetry.

**Remark**: This argument only applies to particles with non-zero dipole moment.

Experimental searches of the neutron electric dipole moment can be found:

- Smith et al. Phys. Rev. **108**, 120 (1957) [[link to paper]](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.108.120).
- Baker et al. Phys. Rev. Lett. **97**, 131801 (2006) [[link to paper]](http://prl.aps.org/abstract/PRL/v97/i13/e131801).

  The upper bound in the last one for $|\mathbf{D}|$ is $2.9 \cdot 10^{-26}$ e cm.

D.

**EDIT**: As David said below, there is not $CPT$ violation in the, hypothetical case, of having $PT$ violation [=existence of non zero electric dipole moment].

Comment: The neutron is composed of $\mathrm{udd}$ valence quarks so charge conjugation would switch it to $\mathrm{\bar u\bar d\bar d}$ - it's not the identity operation. So a neutron electric dipole moment wouldn't automatically violate $CPT$ symmetry. (But other than that, good answer!)

Comment: Well, thank you! I tried to do my best, even though I am not an expert in nuclear/high energy physics.

Comment: "Notice that the only way to know the orientation of your charge distribution ("particle") is by the orientation of the angular momentum." This is exactly the part I don't understand. Electric dipole moment requires only uneven charge distribution, but it does not require those charges to move. Also why are non-zero EDM of atoms not violation of T symmetry?

Comment: Concerning the orientation of the charge distribution, perhaps it is more precise to say "orientation of the electric dipole moment". The electric dipole moment is a vector and to apply, for instance, a parity transformation you need to place it in a reference frame. The $\hat{\mathbf{z}}$ direction in this reference frame is given by the z- component of the angular momentum, $\mathbf{J}=\mathbf{L}+\mathbf{S}$.

Comment: About non-zero EDM of a molecule: it is indeed interesting to think why this not violates $T$ symmetry. This is because the molecule/atoms have non-zero ground states that are invariant under parity so that $T$ needs not to be broken to give non-zero $\mathbf{D}$.

Comment: @DaniH: What are "non-zero ground states"?

Comment: @Karsus Ren: I wanted to say that there exists ground states invariant under parity.

Comment: @DaniH: And why doesn't neutron have such states?

Comment: If the neutron has ground states which are invariant under parity, then $\mathbf{D}$ must vanish. As far as I know, this is what experiments say but theoretically it remains one unsolved puzzle of the Standard Model.